# Cannot convert [Int] to [Int] in generic implementation

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

Trying to create a generic data source I bumped into this error and I was wondering why this isn't compilable.

The error:

**Cannot convert return expression of type '[Int]' to return type '[Int]'**

The code:

```
protocol DataSource {
    func getData<T> () -> [T]
}

class IntDataSource<Int>: DataSource {
    let data:[Int] = []
    func getData<Int>() -> [Int] {
        return data
    }
}
```

The error is thrown on the return statement in IntDataSource.

I know this could be done in better ways with

```
typealias DataType
var data: DataType? { get }
```

But I'm mainly interested in why the compiler doesn't want to accept the return statement. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Part of the question is also why if the previous code is not compilable is the following fair game?

```
class IntDataSource<Int>: DataSource {
    func getData<Int>() -> [Int] {
        let data:[Int] = []
        return data
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

This version also compiles without issues

```
class IntDataSource<Int>: DataSource {

    func getData<Int>() -> [Int] {
        return getIntData()
    }

    func getIntData<Int>() -> [Int] {
        let data:[Int] = []
        return data
    }
}
```

Comment: Protocol cannot really be generic. That's the whole point of associated types (`typealias`). Swift won't see the connection between the generic type `T` in the protocol and `<Int>` after `IntDataSource`. I am not really sure why using `<T>` is even allowed in the protocol declaration though because it doesn't make sense to use a generic type in a protocol.

Comment: Yes, a protocol can't be generic but it seems the functions within can be... Also why would that mean [Int] can't be recognised as [Int] is this just a bad compiler error message?

Comment: `return [Int]()` is accepted, something's wrong but what?

Comment: I have to say that I am lost. I don't think that generics in a protocol should even work but obviously some examples can be compiled.

Comment: All right, the problem is that when you write `<Int>` you are actually creating a generic parameter where `Int` is the name of the parameter so you get a name conflict with the `Int` type.

Comment: @Sulthan: Sorry, I did not see your comment while writing the answer.

Comment: @MartinR No problem, I don't care about points but this is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "strange" compiler error

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '[Int]' to return type '[Int]'
```

can be explained as follows:

Both the `<Int>` in your class definition and the `<Int>` 
in the method definition introduce a new generic
type placeholder called `Int` (and therefore the outer `<Int>` hides the global type  with the same name, and the inner `<Int>` hides the
outer one). Your class definition is equivalent to

```
class IntDataSource<A>: DataSource {
    let data:[A] = []
    func getData<B>() -> [B] {
        return data 
    }
}
```

And now the compiler error is understandable:

```
cannot convert return expression of type '[A]' to return type '[B]'
```

Comment: Is there actually a valid way to use a protocol with a generic type on a method? I couldn't find one.

Comment: @Sulthan: A generic method `func getData<T>() -> [T] { return [] }` in the class would satisfy the protocol. But that is not very useful because `T` is unrelated to any concrete type used in the class.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that's the problem I have found. Even with a `where A == B`  I am not able to compile it.