# Swift compiler error for generic dictionary class: cannot invoke 'removeValue' with an argument list of type '(forKey K)'

Tags: swift, generics, concurrency

I've created a simple dictionary class to be used for synchronized access to a dictionary across multiple threads.  I'm using a DispatchQueue to synchronize the reading and writing of values from the dictionary.  I'm using generic so that it can be used with any dictionary types K:Hashable for the key and T for the object.

Here's an example of the class:

```
public class SynchronizedDictionary<K, T> where K: Hashable {

    private var accessQueue: DispatchQueue!

    private var internalDict: [K: T]

    init(queueName: String) {
        accessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: queueName, qos: .default)
        internalDict = [:]
    }

    func removeValue<K:Hashable>(forKey key: K) {
        accessQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.internalDict.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

When attempting to call the removeValue function on the dictionary class, the compiler errors with the following:
"Cannot invoke 'removeValue' with an argument list of type '(forKey: K)'

[image: Cannot invoke 'removeValue' with an argument list of type '(forKey: K)]

Any idea why I can't call this removeValue function with the generic type?

Comment: Essentially the same error as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891280/cannot-convert-int-to-int-in-generic-implementation – `func removeValue<K:Hashable>(...)` introduces a new local generic placeholder `K`. Just make it `func removeValue(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `removeValue` should be implemented.

```
func removeValue(forKey key: K) {
    accessQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        self.internalDict.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Notice how I removed the generic parameter `K` from the method and instead used the generic parameter `K` from the class declaration.

You cannot use a *new* generic type parameter `K` because that might be a different type than the dictionary's key type, which is `K` from the *class declaration*. If you could do this, something like this would have been possible:

```
SynchronizedDictionary<Int, Int>(queueName: "myQueue").removeValue(forKey: "myKey")
```

The `K` parameter for `removeValue` would have been inferred to `String`. Obviously this makes no sense at all, so you are not allowed to do this.

Comment: Aha.  Thanks!  I removed the generic specification on the method and was able to successfully compile and test.

Answer (score 1):

You already set K as Hashable type with :

public class SynchronizedDictionary **where K: Hashable** {
...
}

so in removeValue :

```
func removeValue(forKey key: K) {
    accessQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        self.internalDict.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks correct.  I've accept a similar answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make `removeValue` generic, since by making it generic, you create a new local generic type, `K`, which won't be the same as the generic type of your class. Simply remove the generic type from the function declaration and just use `K`, which you have access to since you are defining a new instance function of the generic type.

```
public class SynchronizedDictionary<K, T> where K: Hashable {

    private var accessQueue: DispatchQueue!

    private var internalDict: [K: T]

    init(queueName: String) {
        accessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: queueName, qos: .default)
        internalDict = [:]
    }

    func removeValue(forKey key: K) {
        accessQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.internalDict.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works.  I accepted another answer with the same details.